# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 139.162.44.23:587

Tags: c#, smtp, localhost, mime, mailkit

```
var email = new MimeMessage();

email.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("CMPL", "superuser@cmplin.com"));
email.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", cu.Email.ToString()));
email.Cc.Add(new MailboxAddress("", "digitalhealth@cmplin.com"));
email.Bcc.Add(new MailboxAddress("", "devcmpl@gmail.com"));
email.Subject = "Thank you for contacting M/s Chowgule Mediconsult";

string Body = string.Format("Dear {0}. \n\nThank you for submitting your request to M/s Chowgule Mediconsult Pvt. Ltd. We have received the same. \n\nOur team will contact you in 2 working days. In case you have any further queries, please feel free to contact digitalhealth@cmplin.com. \n\nRegards, \n\nTeam CMPL", cu.Name);

email.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Plain)
{  
    Text = Body
};

// email.Body = string.Format("Dear User{0}" + cu.Name);
using (var smtp = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
{
    smtp.Connect("inpro4.fcomet.com", 587, false);

    // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
    smtp.Authenticate("superuser@cmplin.com", "******");

    smtp.Send(email);
    smtp.Disconnect(true);
}

return "succfull";
```

This code working in on local but when it comes to server it is not working,please help in this

The Error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a
> socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 139.162.44.23:587

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got Answer for this problem this code it was worked on local but not on server what i did is

first i searched this ip address hostname on internet 139.162.44.23
second i changed the port no which is in outlook configuration
third ssl is true

i changed three things 1)host name which i got from internet with the help of
ip adress
2)Port No which is configured in oulook
3)ssl true

```
 using (var smtp = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
        {
            smtp.Connect("inpro4.fcomet.com", 465, true);

            // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
            smtp.Authenticate("superuser@cmplin.com", "******");

            smtp.Send(email);
            smtp.Disconnect(true);
        }
```

This is worked for me,hope it will help others also.